# Django naturaltime results not translating

Tags: python, django, translation

In my settings I have:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pl'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

However, `naturaltime` returns strings in english. Is there something else I need to do to make them translate to Polish? I'm confused.